# Trouble using tableView numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have json that I'm parsing in a separate class and looping through it with:

```
            for( NSDictionary * game in games )
            {
                Game * teamGame = [[Game alloc] initWithJson:game];
                [teamGames addObject:teamGame];
            }
```

teamGames holds values like:

```
{
    awayteam = "Olympics 2014";
    gametime = "2014-05-08 19:00:00";
    hometeam = Finland;
},
{
    awayteam = Latvia;
    gametime = "2014-05-11 19:00:00";
    hometeam = "Olympics 2014";
},
{
    awayteam = "Canada 2013";
    gametime = "2014-07-19 19:00:00";
    hometeam = USA;
},
{
    awayteam = "USA 2014";
    gametime = "2014-01-11 15:00:00";
    hometeam = Sweden;
},
{
    awayteam = "Test 2014";
    gametime = "2013-05-16 10:00:00";
    hometeam = Sweden;
},
{
    awayteam = "Olympics 2014";
    gametime = "2014-12-16 19:00:00";
    hometeam = Sweden;
},
{
    awayteam = "Test 2014";
    gametime = "2014-01-11 15:00:00";
    hometeam = Sweden;
},
```

I want to fill the table headers with non repeating dates and the cell's with the corresponding team names. Same dates need to be placed in the same section. Iv'e been able to fill the table by using `return 1;` in `numberOfRowsInSection` but if theres more then one game it wont be shown.

How can I achieve this?

A dictionary of the dates and array's of games within that date?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you answered your own question...Have a dictionary where the key is the date and the object is an array of games. So in `numberOfRowsInSection` just return the count of the array in the corresponding games array from the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-reading your question, I think this is your solution:

1.) Create an NSMutableArray for each date containing the games for that date.

2.) As you create each array, add it to a NSMutableDictionary with the key set as the Date for that array. [dictionaryVar setObject:yourArrayOfGames forKey:@"TheDateYouWantToUseForThatArray"];

3.) In your `numberOfRowsInSection` method, use the `section` Integer (that the method already has) to get the correct array. Since you can't access a property in a dictionary with an index integer, you'll need to convert the keys in the dict to an array and then use the section integer to grab the correct key, and then finally use it on the array. Should look something like:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfDictKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

`arrayOfDictKeys = [dictionaryVar allKeys];` //(this grabs a list of all the keys in the dictionary)
`NSString *key = [arrayOfDictKeys objectAtIndex:section];` //(this is where you use the `section` var)

```
NSMutableArray *arrayForKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arrayForKey = [dictionaryVar objectForKey:key];
return arrayForKey.count;
```

For this to work, you need to make sure the you insert the Key\Array pairs into your dictionary in the correct order, otherwise using `section` grab your key will probably grab you an unexpected date.

Comment: That will not place same dates in the same section

Comment: I changed my answer to better suit your question after rereading it again. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, I don't remember, but grabbing all the keys in allKeys might disorganize the order of the keys when putting them into the array. They may have to be reordered at that point. Make sure you break-point some stuff to see if the order is being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

In numberOfRowsInSection, simply return the number of items (count) of the array.

The value returned by this method is the number of rows that will appear in the tableview section (as described in the method title).

Comment: I understand tableviews. I dont know how place games that have the same dates in the same sections.